# tf14044 access denied adminconfiguration global permissions

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I am using the online version of TFS 2012 for my project. I am also the administrator to this account and the only one that has this permission.

I added a new person to my team and wanted to verify the Multi-CheckOut box was unchecked and to verify the workspace was set correctly. Every time I click on Team in Visual Studio on my new members desktop, connect them to the TFS server and click on Source Control, the following message pops up.

> tf14044 access denied adminconfiguration global permissions.

However I can get in fine. I tried setting them to Build and Project Administrator, but am still getting the same message. Previously the other members of my team could access the feature just fine without the elevated permissions, and I am pretty sure I have not changed any of the permissions prior to this to not work any longer.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message when I wanted to access ***Team, Team Project Collection Settings, Source Control*** in the Visual Studio IDE. 
What I did was to login as the project owner in VSO and went to ***accountName.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_admin/_security***
I selected the user that was having the problem and allow: ***Edit collection-level information, Create a workspace*** and some more and that fixed for me. 
If you allow all of the Permissions or allow them one by one you could find the right permission that you need for your specific task.

This might help you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98c528d7-8f38-4648-83e2-a98db99a1f93/tf14044-error?forum=tfsgeneral

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error message on all my projects along with errors about specific packages not loading correctly, for instance NuGet Package Manager.
When i uninstalled the NuGet Package Manager this tf14044 error was resolved. 
I decided to share this here if anyone else runs into this problem.
So, try going through your extensions or packages to see if they are the real cause of the problem.
You can also check if it is bound to one project rather than many/all, if that is the case then you probably have to check the permissions or settings for that particular project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created a new Worskpace, and get latest version of my projects, and works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since today.
Adding two accounts to 
Project Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)
and
Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION)
to the Group:
Project Collection Build Service Accounts
solved the issue.

However, I have no idea why this happened, as no configuration changes were done on TFS 2015 Update 2.

Reference:
http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/01/15/troubleshoot-error-tf14044-in-build-vnext-for-tfs2015/